# Want to use single ThreadPoolExecutor in Python rather than using 3 of them in entire code

Tags: python-3.x

I am using ThreadPoolExecutor method for multi-threading in Python. I am using it 3 times in my entire code by using following syntax:

```py
worker_pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
for i in range(x):
   worker_pool.submit(process_queue, seshspec_queue, )
```

Where process_queue is function and passing seshspec_queue arg in it.

I am using similar thing at 3 different places.
So, rather than calling ThreadPoolExecutor everytime needed, I wanted to create a single ThreadPoolExecutor and call it whenever needed in my code.

I have tried creating a function, but that did not work.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can move the code blocks to a separate new method so you can replace duplicates with calls to your new method.

**thread_utils.py**

```
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor

worker_pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)


def submit(process_queue, seshspec_queue, x):
    for i in range(x):
        worker_pool.submit(process_queue, seshspec_queue)
```

**test.py**

```
from thread_utils import submit

submit('arg1', 'arg2', 3)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 
I was thinking the same but could not execute that.